# when I run roslaunch rbx1_bringup turtlebot_minimal_create.launch on turtlebot 2,the following occured,why?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1487314684.230445] Failed to contact device with error: [Distance, angle displacement too big, invalid readings from robot. Distance: 8.20, Angle: 147.45]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254912/when-i-run-roslaunch-rbx1_bringup-turtlebot_minimal_create.launch-on-turtlebot-2,the-following-occured,why?/) by [ICDI](https://answers.ros.org/users/27957/icdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Selma B.](https://answers.ros.org/users/38617/selma-b./) on 2018-11-19**:
Hello,

I have the same problem did you find the solution please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it has something to do with the kobuki base vs the rhoomba base. I am working with a Turtlebot2 with a kobuki base and I got the same error but when I ran roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch instead of roslaunch rbx1_bringup turtlebot_minimal_create.launch, everything worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [Eisen](https://answers.ros.org/users/43555/eisen/) with karma: 16 on 2019-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0